# Promise to execute a particular code first

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, promise

I have the following scenario. Actual Page loading starts, user login is checked for authentication. If access granted, actual page loading completes and user can access the page. If access denied, actual page loading stops and user is redirected to 'access denied' page.

Infact the scenario should be like this. User authentication is checked. if access granted, actual page loading starts and user can access page. If access denied, user is directly directed to 'access denied' page.

can someone tell me how to include promise for this scenario. current code is as follows.

```
 $q.when().then(function () {
    return $rootScope.$emit('resetView', false, 'default');
}).then(function (result) {

    loadNavBar();     //actual page loading starts here
}, function (error) {
    $log.error("Caught an error:", error);
    return $q.reject('New error');
});
```

the below function is loadNavBar() which gets executed. User authentication is done inside of this. Hence page loading starts and then user is checked. I want user to be checked first itself and then load page accordingly depending on his access rights.

```
 var loadNavBar = function () {


    //few functions here to display page.
    //below code to check user authentication

    var serviceURL_CheckUserExists = '/api/Pre/CheckUserExists';

    //ajax to check if user exists in database. give/ deny access based on user present in DB and if user is set as blockuser in db. 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceURL_CheckUserExists,
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.Results.length == 1 && response.Results[0].BlockUser == false) { //user has access if condition is satisfied. 
            $rootScope.myLayout.eventHub.emit('getUserName', response.Results[0].User_ID.trim());

            $scope.role = "";
            var details = response.Results[0];
            for (var parameters in details) {
                if (details[parameters] == true) {
                    $scope.role += parameters + ',';
                }
            }

            $scope.role = $scope.role.replace(/.$/, ".");

            var firstname = response.Results[0].FirstName;
            firstname = firstname.replace(/\s/g, '');
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.username = response.Results[0].FirstName + " " + response.Results[0].LastName;

            });
        }
        else { $window.location.href = '../../../BlockUser.html'; } //block access to actual page and redirect to 'access denied' page.
            }
        }
    });


};
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you mean you want to return a promise from `loadNavBar`?

Comment: page loading starts first and i see a part of the page if user is access denied. i dont want user to see any part of the page when he is not accessed to. he should directly be directed to access denied page.

Comment: Why does the default view of the page already contain the content that the user could be denied acccess to? That content should not even arrive at the client.

Comment: true. tats wat i am tryin to achieve. should i place the authentication part outside of the loadNavbar function. should i include a promise before that to check user authentication ? and if access granted, go and execute loadnavbar

Comment: I actually meant that the authentification part should be on the server.

Comment: It does a ajax call to check user access. database is there to store user details.  i am just retrieving it and giving access to page depending on the database values

Comment: If there is anything private on the page the authentication should be on the server, not the client since it can easily be hacked. For example, I just comment out the redirect line inside dev tools. However, if the content is public and you just want users to register to see the content, client side is fine. In this case, using CSS to hide the content while page loads, then showing once user is approved, would probably be "good enough."

Comment: @KarlGalvez- can you give an example of showing/hiding content through css on the fly when function is executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that the right approach to your problem is to use resolve property in the route, so the user can't navigate to certain pages if he isn't logged in and once he logged in you can inject the user object to the controller

for example to navigate to home page you must be logged in

```
.when("/home", {
templateUrl: "homeView.html",
controller: "homeController",
resolve: {
    user: function(AuthenticationService){
      return AuthenticationService.getUser();
    }
  }
})

app.controller("homeController", function ($scope, user) {
   $scope.user = user;
 });
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-authentication-angular-applications/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example of hiding the content until the user is authenticated to see it. Click the 'authenticate' button to trigger the function that you would run if the user is authenticated by your ajax call. Showing the content can be done with a fuction like:

```
function userIsAuthenticated(){
   document.getElementById('pageContent').style.display = 'block';
}
```

See [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qukuy1n/3/) for a simple implementation.